# What is the origin of 落第?

Tags: etymology

I see how 落 can be a failure. But how is 第 relevant to failing an exam, is this a meaning other than 'number, -th' or implicitly falling *below first* place?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that「落第」is a Chinese loanword. It originally meant *failure to be selected as a ranked Imperial bureaucrat due to unsatisfactory results from the [Imperial Examinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_examination)*.

> [元](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_dynasty)　曾瑞　《留鞋記》楔子：＂人都道我落第無顏，羞歸鄉里＂
>
> *Everyone spoke about me not being selected for Imperial service, and to ashamedly return to my home village*

- 「落」means *to fall to the ground* > *fail*
- 「第」refers to the *grade-ranking result* of a candidate's attempt at the Imperial Examinations (「科第」in Chinese)

  > [北齊](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Qi)　顏之推　《顏氏家訓・勉學》：＂明經求第，則顧人答策。＂
  >
  > *[Testing] one's thorough knowledge of the classics and to obtain Imperial rank, candidates are invited to answer these questions.*

---

**Reference:**

- 《{{kr:漢語}}大詞典》

Comment: This is right. The antonym of 落第 is 及第 (to pass the imperial examination).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this website about etymologies](http://gogen-allguide.com/ra/rakudai.html),

> 「第」は「第何位」などと用いられるように、一段一段の段階をや物事の順序を意味し、転じて、段階ごとの試験も意味するようになった。
>
> そこから、落第は段階ごとの試験に落ちる意味で「不合格」を表すようになった。
>
> 中国では「不合格」の意味で用いられるが、日本では「落第生」と言うように、不合格になることで進級や卒業ができないことも意味する。

Paraphrasing the relevant part about 第: the 第 comes from 第何位 and referred to the stairs in a staircase or the ordering of things. It then evolved to refer to tests that comes in tiers/steps. Then, 落第 would mean to fall down from a step in the sequence of tests.